# Выборка из таблицы

Tags: mysql

Доброго времени суток! Есть такая таблица:

```
+----+-----+------+
| id | uid | chat |
+----+-----+------+
|  3 |   1 |    2 |
|  6 |   1 |    3 |
|  1 |   6 |    1 |
|  4 |   6 |    2 |
|  2 |   9 |    1 |
|  5 |   9 |    3 |
+----+-----+------+
```

Как выбрать chat, где uid равен 1 и 6? При этом, другой запрос может быть на выборку, где uid равен 1,6,9,11;

Comment: Вы в условии противоречите себе. Говорите, что нужно выбрать там, где uid равен 1 или 6, а в самом конце приводите "к примеру 1,6,9,11"

Также, абсолютно не понятно, как рассчитать кол-во участников.

Comment: Не 1 или 6 а 1 И 6. Количество участников рассчитывать не нужно - другой запрос может быть на выборку, где uid = 1,6,9,11.

Comment: тогда ответ короткий - таких строк нет. Так как uid в каждой строке один, то строки, у котрых uid и 1 и 6 одновременно, не существуют.

Comment: мне нужно выбрать обе строки - ту, в которой uid = 6 и ту, в которой uid = 9. И вернуть chat, который у них одинаковый

Comment: Покажите полный результат, который Вы хотите получить. Будет хорошо, если покажете в виде готовой структуры на Вашем любимом языке.

Comment: Для uid = 1 и 6 результатом должно быть chat = 2. ЯП значения не имеет - реализовать надо sql запросом.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * from `table` where `uid` = 1 OR `uid` = 6
```

Comment: Русским по белому написано -> uid должен быть равен 1 И 6. До такой выборки я бы и сам догадался.

Comment: @woland Вы сами-то понимаете, чего хотите? Таких записей нет и быть не может.

Comment: нужно выбрать 2 записи - где uid = 6 и uid = 1. Смысл запроса в том, чтобы получить поле чат, которое будет одинаковым у этих двух строк

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял идею, то здесь используется комбинированный запрос.
В этом случае встречал запись через UNION:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `uid` = 1 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `uid` = 6
```

Comment: В этом запросе union будет работать как in. Это не подходит

Answer (score 0):

Что сложного? Выбираем все чаты для одного уид, все чаты для второго уид, сравниваем. Вуаля!

```
+------+
| chat |
+------+
|    2 |
+------+
```

Идея ясна?

Answer (score 0):

Может я чего сильно недопонял, но чем плох такой запрос:

```
SELECT `chat` FROM `yourTable` WHERE `uid` = 1 AND `uid` = 6
```

Выдирает из таблицы все поля `chat`, `uid` у которых 1 и 6:

```
+------+
|  chat|
+------+
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    1 |
|    2 |
+------+
```

Соответствует условию задачи.